# How do I set a field value?

Tags: 8, entities

I am using the following code, but it doesn't set the field value as I would expect.

```php
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update().
 */
function mymodule_node_update(EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->getType() == "article") {
    $entity->set('field_set_color', ["red","green"]);
  }
}
```

Why doesn't this code set the field value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x) `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update()` gives the following warning.

> When saving existing entities, the entity is assumed to be complete, partial updates of entities are not supported.

```php
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
    
function mymodule_node_presave(NodeInterface $node) {
  if ($node->getType() == "article") {
    $node->set('field_set_color', ["red","green"]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update/8.2.x) isn't the hook to change entity data. It's invoked after the entity has been updated and saved in the database. The documentation itself makes that clear. (Emphasis is mine.)

> This hook runs **once the entity storage has been updated**. Note that hook implementations **may not alter the stored entity data**.

The only hook that is invoked right before the entity is saved in the database is [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.2.x). Contrary to `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update()`, this hook is invoked either when an entity is created or when an entity is updated. If you only want to change a field value when an entity is updated, your code should be similar to the following one.

```php
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
    
function mymodule_node_presave(NodeInterface $node) {
  if (!$node->isNew() && $node->getType() == "article") {
    $node->set('field_set_color', ["red","green"]);
  }
}
```

The code is using `NodeInterface` as type-hinting because that is the interface that defines [`getType()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21NodeInterface.php/function/NodeInterface%3A%3AgetType/8.2.x). Alternatively, you can use the following code, which works since `EntityInterface` defines [`bundle()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/function/EntityInterface%3A%3Abundle/8.2.x).

```php
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave().
 */
function mymodule_node_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {
  if (!$entity->isNew() && $entity->bundle() == "article") {
    $entity->set('field_set_color', ["red","green"]);
  }
}
```

Since the code you need is for the Node entity, I would use the first snippet. I would use the second snippet when the code needs to run for any  content entity, not just nodes.